# Wicket Updating Image using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wicket, wicket-1.5

I'm trying to update an image using JavaScript when the user focuses on a text field. Currently have the following HTML/Wicket code:

```
<div class="input-prepend">
    <span class="add-on">
        <wicket:link>
            <img src="img/username-img-1.png" id="username-img"/>
        </wicket:link>
    </span>
    <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="User Name" wicket:id="username" />
</div>
```

And the following JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#username').focus(function() {
        $('#username-img').attr("src","img/username-img-2.png" );
    });
});
```

Obviously, this does not work, since Wicket has it's own way of referencing resources. I'd like to know my other options. Thanks!

Comment: Could you could place the images in a static resources folder? Or are the images generated?

Comment: I have them in a package within `src/main/resources/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you have the image in `webapp` folder. So the problem is that you need to rewrite the URL to be context relative using `UrlUtils.rewriteToContextRelative`.

Something like this might work:

```
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {

    StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
    script.append("$('#username').focus(function() {");
    script.append("$('#username-img').attr(\"src\",\"");
    script.append(UrlUtils.rewriteToContextRelative("img/logo.png", RequestCycle.get()));
    script.append("\");");
    script.append("});");

    response.render(OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript(script.toString()));
}
```

Comment: Actually, I have my image in a package under `src/main/resources` relative to my CSS (also found in `src/main/resources`)